# How do I find the max value in a separate from a list of indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of the following form:

```
 results = [[71, 84, 97, 106, 154, 183, 251, 283, 320],
 [354, 368, 381, 395, 435, 466, 511, 565, 602],
 [636, 650, 661, 671, 712, 741, 789, 850, 887],
 [921, 935, 947, 956, 1000, 1032, 1084, 1111, 1117, 1146, 1167, 1171, 1186],
 [1220, 1233, 1246, 1256, 1298, 1330, 1395, 1401, 1413, 1440, 1482]]
```

These values are index values for a dataframe called `volt` which contains voltage readings. A snippet of the volt DF looks like this:

| T | voltage |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.450 |
| 1 | -0.460 |
| 2 | -0.475 |
| 3 | -0.480 |
| 4 | -0.410 |
| 5 | -0.312 |
| 6 | -0.124 |
| 7 | -0.324 |
| 8 | -0.634 |
| 9 | -0.673 |
| 10 | -0.918 |

For example, running the following code:

```
print(volt[results[0][0]])
```

Will print the following:

```
-0.69
```

I want to find the values in each list of the results list that correspond to the the maximum voltage readings. To clarify, the first list in the results list is:

```
[71, 84, 97, 106, 154, 183, 251, 283, 320]
```

The value volt[106] is the maximum voltage value in this list, and volt[320] is the minimum voltage reading in this list. I want to identify those.

The code I have to do this is as follows:

```
max_vals = []
min_vals = []

for i in results:
    max_vals.append(max(volt[i]))
    min_vals.append(min(volt[i]))
```

When I run this, I am returned a list of the max and min voltage readings. Instead, I want the the value in the results list that corresponds to that reading.

What can I change in my code to achieve this?

Comment: post a testable fragment of `volt` df

Comment: `results[0][max(((i, volt[e]) for i, e in enumerate(results[0])), key=lambda arg: arg[1])[0]]`?

Comment: the fragment posted has string columns and can not be indexed by a number `volt[results[0][0]]`. The posted code contradicts with a df fragment

Answer (score 1):

Take the `max`/`min` of the `results` list, using a `key` that fetches the associated result from `volt`.  I can't easily verify that this exact code works since you didn't provide a test value for `volt`, but something along these lines should work:

```
max_vals = [max(r, key=v.__getitem__) for r, v in zip(results, volt)]
min_vals = [min(r, key=v.__getitem__) for r, v in zip(results, volt)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) function:

```
max_vals = [df[i].idxmax(axis=1) for i in results]
min_vals = [df[i].idxmin(axis=1) for i in results]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a numpy solution:

First some setup to illustrate the point with smaller data:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> volt = np.random.randn(9).round(2)
>>> volt
array([ 0.01,  0.59, -0.56,  0.8 ,  0.94, -0.29, -0.3 ,  0.16, -1.18])

>>> results = np.random.permutation(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> results
array([[4, 0, 5],
       [6, 3, 7],
       [8, 1, 2]])
```

Numpy is nice in the sense that we can now get the relevant voltages using our results by simply indexing:

```
>>> volt[results]
array([[ 0.94,  0.01, -0.29],
       [-0.3 ,  0.8 ,  0.16],
       [-1.18,  0.59, -0.56]])
```

We can use `argmax` and `argmin` with `axis=1` to find the integer index locations of the maximum and minimum of each row:

```
>>> max_indices = volt[results].argmax(axis=1)
>>> max_indices
array([0, 1, 1], dtype=int64)

>>> min_indices = volt[results].argmin(axis=1)
>>> min_indices
array([2, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

Finally, we use these indices to find the original result values:

```
>>> rows = np.arange(results.shape[0])

>>> maxima = results[rows, max_indices]
>>> maxima
array([4, 3, 1])

>>> minima = results[rows, min_indices]
>>> minima
array([5, 6, 8])
```

Answer (score 1):

If 'T' is your locator that is present in `results` then you could do:

```
max_values = [volt.set_index('T').loc[row].max() for row in results]
min_values = [volt.set_index('T').loc[row].min() for row in results]
```